# XPath for extracting image scr with style attribute with the help of Screaming Frog

Tags: xpath, xpath-2.0, xpath-1.0

My goal is to extract image URLs together with style attribute (width and height) with the help of Screaming Frog.

```
<p style="text-align: center;"><img alt="Scary games are all about submerging into unknown territories" src="//cdn01.x-plarium.com/browser/content/blog/images/2022/scary-games-2.webp" style="width: 640px; height: 426px;"></p>
```

I am adding the following XPath for custom extraction - //img[contains(@style)]/@src
But getting errors for this.

Will really appreciate any help.

Comment: Can you share all your code including the link to the page you working on?

Comment: here is the link to the full data - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16j3153OTAsOYUnXYNDQvNCBx42EOGFJ16FZv3T21pks/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: OK, and what about your code trials? including current errors if any?

Comment: sorry, I updated the cell

Comment: That's not a code...

Comment: I added the XPath that I am using in Screaming Frog

Comment: I understand. But this is not a code while for minimal debugging we have to your code trials, not only the excel file like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your XPath below contains an error

```xml
//img[contains(@style)]/@src
```

The `contains` functions expects *two* parameters. You have only passed one (`@style`). The parameters are both strings; if the second string is a substring of the first then the function returns true, otherwise it returns false.

If you just want to check that the `style` attribute has some value (any value) then the following will work:

```xml
//img[@style]/@src
```

If you want to check that the `style` attribute contains some particular string (e.g. `'width'`) then you want something like this:

```xml
//img[contains(@style, 'width')]/@src
```

Comment: @ConanTuohy  Thanks a million! Wanted to ask you if it's possbile to scrape the whole string, so that in the result I would have, e.g. <img alt="Scary games are all about submerging into unknown territories" src="//cdn01.x-plarium.com/browser/content/blog/images/2022/scary-games-2.webp" style="width: 640px; height: 426px;">   -  I would need to see the numbers for the width and height.

Comment: I don't know Screaming Frog at all, and I know a lot of other XPath environments seem to be quite limited, in what you can return, but you could try returning an XPath 2.0 sequence of strings each consisting of the URL, then a space, then the style attribute: `for $image in //img return concat(@src, ' ', @style)`

Comment: NB this is not a "string" for your XPath interpreter: `<img alt="Scary games are all about submerging into unknown territories" src="//cdn01.x-plarium.com/browser/content/blog/images/2022/scary-games-2.webp" style="width: 640px; height: 426px;">`; it's actually parsed into elements with attributes. If you want strings you'd need to generate them from the attribute values (as in my previous comment)